# Is it possible to import js file to another js file, just like in sass

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to **import a javascript file** to another javascript file, just like we import sass files?

> This question might have been masked as a duplicate to some other question. But it is not because I know that we can concat two or more JavaScript files.
>
> But I looking for a better. I like the idea of importing files in sass (I am looking for the same process, in JavaScript).
>
> As it will also help to send only 1 request to the server.

Comment: Yes you can import with `import` ..

Comment: How to import it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `require.js` or node `export` and `import` syntax. But you'll have to write ES6 JavaScript Code which is the next version to support import and export statements. Using a transpiler such as babel you can compile those ES6 code to ES5 which browser understands.

Read more about ES6 module system and babel here.
https://babeljs.io/learn-es2015/#ecmascript-2015-features-modules